# openjdk platform binary use so much memory when build android app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, java

When I build android app it can take from 5 minutes to 15 minutes.
How to solve problem whith memory. Is there a way to reduce memory consumption?
How make build faster?

my **build.gradle** :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile('com.philliphsu:bottomsheetpickers:2.3.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'gridlayout-v7'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.philliphsu:bottomsheetpickers:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

also my **gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

also add report
[image]

Why it takes so long and how you can speed up the assembly of the project?

Comment: Not using Jack (which is deprecated and will be removed) will speed things up a lot.

Comment: @ BladeCoder - Should I use  'retrolambda' instead Jack?

Comment: No, you should use version 3.0.0 of the Android Gradle plugin (still alpha, but more stable than Jack) https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html I think you can use it without upgrading the whole Android Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution - not using Jack. Read here https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html

Thanks [@BladeCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602791/bladecoder)

Answer (score 7):

Everyone will give different different opinions, but I recently fixed it by disabling my Antivirus Software. Disable the firewall, because it interrupts the Gradle Daemon from starting so OpenJDK Platform binary will be keep executing again n again, ultimately the memory out of crash will happen for the system.

**UPDATE:** Make sure, **Wireless Hotspot** is Turned Off. That's most important, while building the Project, the Hotspot must not be On.

Do this, and Thanks me later

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...

Gradle Daemon started in 4 s 291 ms

Starting Gradle Daemon...

Gradle Daemon started in 5 s 664 ms

Starting Gradle Daemon...

Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 210 ms

Starting Gradle Daemon...

Gradle Daemon started in 7 s 258 ms
```